# Typescript Type or Lint to prevent accidentally rendering the actual function into JSX, instead of the executed return value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I'm hoping to find a solution that would prevent me from the dumb mistake I too often make represented by the following:

```
export function scratch_1 (props: scratch_1Props): ReactElement | null {
    function renderA (): string {
        return "A";
    }

    function renderB (): string {
        return "B";
    }

    function renderC (): string {
        return "C";
    }

    function render (): ReactElement | null {
        return (
            <div className={cx(styles._)}>
                {renderA()}
                {renderB()}
                {renderC} //BUG
            </div>
        );
    }

    return render();
}
```

Notice that `renderC` should be `renderC()`. It's not the end of the world, but every once in while it causes me an annoying 5 minutes of confused debugging.

I'm hoping there's a simple linter solution, though I can imagine it being a bit difficult, since there are times someone could want to pass a reference to a function as a prop to a component, so there might be some overlap there.

But I could imagine someone who's really hammered on types and jsx component children the like, might have a more meta solution. I've had little luck with smart enforcing of child types in jsx.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like this is possible with `tslint` out of the box.  You could create your own linting rule, per [the instructions to do so](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/).

Another solution could be to change the way you're writing the JSX.  To be fair, this doesn't really solve your problem the way you hoped.  Basically, just store the output of your `render{X}` functions to an inlined `const`.  This prevents the assignment of function signatures to things that should only be assigned strings.

You could do something very similar a number of different ways, but here's the way I wrote it up for illustration purposes (I changed the values of some things because I couldn't pull in types for them, like the component's `className`):

```
import * as React from "react";

export function scratch_1 (props: {}): React.ReactElement | null {
    function renderA (): string {
        return "A";
    }

    function renderB (): string {
        return "B";
    }

    function renderC (): string {
        return "C";
    }

    function joinThoseRenders(): string {
        return [renderA(), renderB(), renderC()].join("\n");
    }

    function render (): React.ReactElement | null {
        const stringyJoe: string = joinThoseRenders();

        return (
            <div className={""}>
                {stringyJoe}
            </div>
        );
    }

    return render();
}
```

Comment: The string types were just a simplification. It would be varied and complex in reality. I think having to pull out every rendering based function and store them in local variables first probably causes more headaches than it saves. Now they all need keys; and you’ve got to manually include types on the variables, otherwise you’re back unit the same problem, etc. but thanks for thinking about it.